# Perl - Find differences in values inside string on many hashes which has ID in key name

Tags: perl, pcre

I have a lot config files with parameters for external program. My script will test all of these configs print to STDOUT and CSV. But to get this script interface more readable I would print name of file and changed parameters for each files.

Here are examples. My hash of hashes looks like this:

```
$hoh{string 1}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 threshold_buy_bull = 1.9 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.6';
$hoh{string 5}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 threshold_buy_bull = 2.1 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.6';
$hoh{string 8}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.4 threshold_buy_bull = 2.1 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.7';
$hoh{another string 1}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 1.9 dedede = -0.6 threshold = -0.6';
$hoh{another string 2}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 2.1 dedede = -0.5 threshold = -0.6';
$hoh{another string 3}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 2.0 dedede = -0.6 threshold = -0.6';
```

And I would like to achieve a result such as using the following lines ...

```
$hoh{string 1}{values} = '2.5 1.9 -0.6';
$hoh{string 5}{values} = '2.5 2.1 -0.6';
$hoh{string 8}{values} = '2.4 2.1 -0.7';
$hoh{another string 1}{values} = '1.9 -0.6';
$hoh{another string 2}{values} = '2.1 -0.5';
$hoh{another string 3}{values} = '2.0 -0.6';
```

So my script output will be generate STDOUT something like this:

```
test of string 1 with values 2.5 1.9 -0.6
test of string 5 with values 2.5 2.1 -0.6
test of string 8 with values 2.4 2.1 -0.7
test of another string 1 with values 1.9 -0.6
test of another string 2 with values 2.1 -0.5
test of another string 3 with values  2.0 -0.6
```

... with the difference that I would like the script to search for values that are changing for me.

Longer expiration:
I would like to store this data in a hash of hashes, and then find values that change at least once from a given 'string' or 'another string' and assign it to the value key in the given hash of hashes. The key is a string and a random number. The script should only compare the hash values, in which the string is identical (as if you cut off all the digits from the keys), ie the value key {string}! = {Another string} and {string 1} = {string 2}. I emphasize that the hash values {config} are very variable. Commonly `/(threshold_buy_bull = )\d+/` is not enough.

Comment: I think this looks like an XY problem. Strings of values embedded in hashes looks like something is being done in a bad way. Could you clarify a bit please? Because my suggestion would be start by splitting your 'key-value' string into a sub-hash, and then compare field by field. But I'm not clear enough on what you're trying to do to hammer out an answer.

Comment: I havent other ideas than like You in this comment. Its why I add answer here. I will update my question.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so first of all - I'd say storing your data in substrings is the wrong way to do this. Decompose those into the key-value pairs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %hoh; 

$hoh{"string 1"}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 threshold_buy_bull = 1.9 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.6';
$hoh{"string 5"}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 threshold_buy_bull = 2.1 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.6';
$hoh{"string 8"}{conf} = 'SMA_long = 712 SMA_short = 38 decay = 0.0076 learning_rate = 0.27 min_predictions = 20 momentum = 0.09 price_buffer_len = 88 threshold_buy_bear = 2.4 threshold_buy_bull = 2.1 threshold_sell_bear = -0.6 threshold_sell_bull = -0.7';
$hoh{"another string 1"}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 1.9 dedede = -0.6 threshold = -0.6';
$hoh{"another string 2"}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 2.1 dedede = -0.5 threshold = -0.6';
$hoh{"another string 3"}{conf} = 'threshold_buy_bear = 2.5 HNA_long = 712  aaaaa = 0.0076 ccccc = 0.27 bbbbbbb = 2.0 dedede = -0.6 threshold = -0.6';

print Dumper \%hoh;

foreach my $conf ( values %hoh ) { 
   print $conf -> {conf};
   $conf = { map { /(\w+) = ([\d\.\-]+)/g } $conf -> {conf} };
}

print Dumper \%hoh;
```

That way you end up with `%hoh`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'another string 2' => {
                                  'threshold' => '-0.6',
                                  'ccccc' => '0.27',
                                  'bbbbbbb' => '2.1',
                                  'dedede' => '-0.5',
                                  'threshold_buy_bear' => '2.5',
                                  'HNA_long' => '712',
                                  'aaaaa' => '0.0076'
                                },
```

... etc

Now, I can't tell where your "values" are coming from in your second example, but it should hopefully be a lot easier to compare.

You can get the 3 values that I  *think* you're looking for:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %hoh ) { 
   print $key, " => ", $hoh{$key}{threshold_buy_bear},"\n";
}
```

Or just do it with a hash slice:

```
my @values = qw ( threshold_buy_bear threshold_buy_bull threshold_sell_bull );

foreach my $key ( sort keys %hoh ) { 
   print $key, " => ", join ( " ", @{$hoh{$key}}{@values} ), "\n";
}
```

Comment: I wrote in question: "I emphasize that the hash values {config} are very variable. Commonly /(threshold_buy_bull = )\d+/ is not enough."
So I can't define string like 'threshold_buy_bear'. Its various string. Different vaues can be anything. But thanks for map example. Im sure it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be one single expression something like

```
my $temp = '';
while ($hoh{$hashkey}{conf} =~ m/(\S+)\s*=\s*(\S+)/gc) {
  my ($key, $value) = ($1, $2);
  # replace the condition of the if by anything you need;
  # it's just an example on top of the OP's example
  if ($key =~ m/^threshold/) {
    $temp .= ((length($temp) ? ' ' : '') . $value);
  }
}
$hoh{$hashkey}{values} = $temp;
```

for each key `$hashkey` might do? Each iteration of the `while` loop will process one match. The values of the key value pair matched get concatenated in a temporary string which then is assigned to the hash.

Comment: I wrote in question: "I emphasize that the hash values {config} are very variable. Commonly /(threshold_buy_bull = )\d+/ is not enough."

Comment: @J. Doe: Yes I did read that. I didn't intend to post a turnkey solution. I just wanted to point you to the direction, if one pattern doesn't fit all, try with a loop over a pattern to split the big problem into smaller, maybe easier ones ones. Of course it's up to you, to adapt that to your needs. I edited my answer to emphasize this more clearly.